# How calculate a double integral accurately using python

Tags: python, math, computer-science, integral, numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate a double integral given by :

```
import scipy.special as sc
from numpy.lib.scimath import sqrt as csqrt
from scipy.integrate import dblquad


def g_re(alpha, beta, k, m):
    psi = csqrt(alpha ** 2 + beta ** 2 - k ** 2)
    return np.real(
        sc.jv(m, alpha)
        * sc.jv(m, beta)
        * sc.jv(m, alpha)
        * np.sin(beta)
        * sc.jv(m, -1j * psi)
        * np.exp(-psi)
        / (alpha ** 2 * psi)
    )


def g_im(alpha, beta, k, m):
    psi = csqrt(alpha ** 2 + beta ** 2 - k ** 2)
    return np.imag(
        sc.jv(m, alpha)
        * sc.jv(m, beta)
        * sc.jv(m, alpha)
        * np.sin(beta)
        * sc.jv(m, -1j * psi)
        * np.exp(-psi)
        / (alpha ** 2 * psi)
    )


k = 5
m = 0

tuple_args = (k, m)
ans = dblquad(g_re, 0.0, np.inf, 0, np.inf, args=tuple_args)[0]
ans += 1j * dblquad(g_im, 0.0, np.inf, 0, np.inf, args=tuple_args)[0]
```

The integration intervals are along the positive real axes ([0, np.inf[). When calculating I got the following warning :

```
/tmp/a.py:10: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  sc.jv(m, alpha)
g/home/nschloe/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py:879: IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
  If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze
  the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a
  local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will
  probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator
  on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
  quad_r = quad(f, low, high, args=args, full_output=self.full_output,
```

I subdivided the domain of integration but I still got the same warning. Could you help me please.

Comment: I don't see any integral in the code you gave? Just the definition of a function.

Comment: Ok I added some code

Comment: Try to pick a large number and go from there to infinity. It might be a bit hard to converge.

Comment: I tried that. I also made a change on the integration variable gamma1 = 1 / alpha and gamma2 = 1 / beta to make the interval of integration given by finite numbers. I still get the same warning

Comment: Code examples should be _minimal_ to make the essence of the problem clearer. In your code, for example, I'm sure you can remove almost all variables.